# MSMQ Outgoing Queue Timout Duration for failed transmissions

Tags: msmq

Most systems have default timeout durations if expected behavior is not achieved.  For example, SQL Server has a connection timeout and a command time out.  Web services typically have a time out period waiting for a response.

For MSMQ, when I attempt to send a message to an invalid host, I see the message in the originating host's outgoing queue with a state of 'Waiting to connect' and history showing 'Name resolution failed...'.

How long will this stay in the outgoing queues area?  Will it ever move to a dead-letter queue?  Are there controls to define this duration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want [message timers](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc736871%28WS.10%29.aspx).

Time To Reach Queue controls when message goes to Dead Letter Queue.

Comment: Thanks John, that helps a lot!